# Different output when executing statement directly and from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sql Server 2008 is behaving in a strange way. When I execute the stored procedure the out put is in a different order than when I execute the statements directly for the same parameters. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help!!!

Here is a simple query structure and explain what it does.

```
Top 10 Query1
Union all
Top 10 Query2
Order by name
```

a. When u run it in a proc :
From Query 1 it fetches top 10 , then from query 2 it fetches top 10 and then finally it does the order

b. When you open the query :
From Query 1 it applies the order and then fetches top 10, and from Query 2 it also applies the order and then fetches top 10

This is strange that it's doing 2 different things with the same query.

```
Output from Procedure
Name                                          Cost Price
A2 Bag Stickerss DO NOT STOCKTAKES               24
aaaaaa                                           5
aaaaaa                                           7.5


Output from Query
Name                                          Cost Price
A2 Bag Stickerss DO NOT STOCKTAKES               24
A2 Bag Stickerss DO NOT STOCKTAKES               27
aaaaaa                                           5
aaaaaa                                           7.5
aaaaaa                                           9
```

Comment: Do you have an `ORDER BY` clause in your stored proc and your ad-hoc query?? Without any `ORDER BY` there is **no** guaranteed order - you could get anything at all

Comment: Hi Marc_s, Both piece of code has order by clause.

Comment: An identical ORDER BY ?? Then you should get the same result.... (except for those columns that aren't ordered). Can you **show us** the query??

Comment: Order by clause is identical.. I will add the query output in the Question.

Comment: Add the query as well please. That output isn't different order it is different (extra) results.

Comment: It does not look like you are running the same query or you are not using the same data. The order of rows is not different. You have more rows returned when using the query version.

Comment: Hi Mikael. I am definitely running the same query.

Comment: Are you sure that the content of your temp table is the same when running the query and the SP?

Comment: Temp table is created at the beginning and dropped at the end of the procedure call. I am using exactly the same code for the query and same parameters. So I believe the data in temp table should be same in both case. But I will double check it..

Comment: Hi MIkael, Temp table data is same for procedure and query

Comment: I don't see any other reasons for different results other than content of temp table or values of parameters. I believe it is quite unusual to have SP dependent of a temp table created outside the scope of the SP but it should not be any problems if it is setup right. In SQL Server 2008 you could use a table valued parameter instead.

Comment: Hi Mikael, I have found a fix. The problem lie in the way Top, Union and Order by clause is used in this query. I have changed the query to do Select Top 10* From (Select Query 2 union Select Query 2) order by column... the query gives the same output :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic.

It just means "Select any 10 records". So you are selecting an arbitrary set of 10 results from query 1 and an arbitrary set of 10 records from query 2 then ordering these 20 records by name.

Which `TOP 10` you end up with depends on the plan chosen (which may well be different in the stored procedure) You would need to add an order by (on a set of columns with no ties) to each query to make it deterministic.

Your current query is like

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM master..spt_values
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM master..spt_values
ORDER BY name
```

[image: Plan 1]

You see that SQL Server just adds a `TOP` iterator to both branches of the plan to limit the output of both queries then these feed into the Union and the sort by name happens after that. SQL Server chose a clustered index scan for this so the results will likely be the TOP 10 in clustered index order `type,number,name` (though this shouldn't be relied upon either, without a specified order by to indicate what the `TOP` refers to **any** set of 10 rows would be valid. It would be perfectly valid for it to use the [advanced scanning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx) feature here and give you an arbitrary 10 rows that it knows to be in cache as they have just been read by an other query's scan.)

To rewrite the query with `TOP...ORDER BY` specified for each element you could use CTEs as below.

```
;WITH Query1 AS
(
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM master..spt_values
ORDER BY name,number,type
), Query2 AS
(
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM master..spt_values
ORDER BY number,type,name
)

SELECT * 
FROM Query1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Query2
ORDER BY name
```

[image: Plan 2]